# Is the "Civic Duty" badge awarder a little eager?

Tags: support, voting, badges

I've been granted the "Civic Duty" badge on Stack Overflow. However, looking at [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519348/tzhx) I'm still five votes away from qualifying for it -- it says only 295 votes cast.

What causes this? Is it a bug?

Clarification: the number I'm looking at is on the front page of my profile. If I drill down and examine still existing votes (e.g. discount deleted ones), the numbers are different again. So I'm fairly confident the view on front page includes votes that are deleted.

Comment: It may be counting votes on deleted posts

Comment: I don't remember for sure, but I feel like the votes displayed there don't count votes on deleted posts, but the badge does.

Comment: @Kendra I don't think that's the case, pretty sure those are still counted on the "summary" of the profile. If I click through for more detail, for example, it then shows an even greater reduction (e.g. number of down votes goes from 150 to 80.

Comment: Another answer could very well be that the vote count on the summary page is cached and you have actually voted over 300 times.

Comment: The summary of votes does include votes on deleted posts. It is also heavily cached (which is quite annoying, honestly). @Kendra is probably right: you already voted 300 times but the number is yet to be updated.

Comment: @Kendra that MSE post may be outdated (2011). An explanation I've got 2 years after it [at Progs meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5445/31260) was that "deleted posts... votes do show up in your totals, [and also count toward various badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions/123048#123048)..."

Comment: @gnat Thanks, I was looking for something more recent to be more sure.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The vote count on your profile summary is *cached*. It'll almost certainly be out of date and you already cast those 5 extra votes.

In other words: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ holds the key.